# where i shall get my ServiceDefinition.csdef file?

Tags: c#, azure, crystal-reports

I have a problem related to crystal report in azure server.I followded the below link and did all setting as per mentioned.But to create the last step i need a "ServiceDefinition.csdef".Can anyone help where shall i get this?

Thie link is-
http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/crystal-reports-on-azure-how-to.html

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from the link that you provided, but when you adding a new project to your solution with **Windows Azure Cloud Service** template you will find **ServiceDefinition.csdef** file in this new project.

In **Windows Azure Cloud Service** project you can manage all required stuff to deploy your WCF service to the Azure.

[See this link about hosting your wcf service on the Azure Cloud](https://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/09/08/create-and-deploy-your-windows-azure-cloud-service/)

Comment: I have already a project  i create a new project to my solution with Windows Azure Cloud Service templateand use it ServiceDefinition.csdef file in my exsisting project.

Answer (score 1):

when you adding a new project to your solution with Windows Azure Cloud Service template, you will find the ServiceDefinition.csdef file